# How to properly train batch-normalization networks with gradient accumulation?

Tags: deep-learning, training, batch-normalization

Using gradient accumulation efficiently replicate training with larger batch sizes for networks that are independent on the batch size. However, networks with BN layers rely on a batch size -- running statistics are calculated on mini-batches instead of full-batch and it could harm the training process.

**My question is**: could we modify gradient accumulation training procedure to allow BN layers (as well as the other layers) to be updated as if we use full-batch? Training step described below seems to be a legit approach.

*Note: `grad_accum` here is a number of mini-batches to accumulate gradients before doing optimization step.*

**Training step**

1. Freeze all the network parameters except for BN layers'.
2. Concatenate `grad_accum` mini-batches into full-batch, calculate loss and accumulate gradients. *Here gradients are calculated only for BN layers and BN layers running statistics are updated for full-batch.*
3. Unfreeze all the network, freeze BN layers. Set BN layers to evaluation mode not to update running stats.
4. Iterate over `grad_accum` mini-batches, calculate and scale loss and accumulate gradients as we do in a usual gradient accumulation procedure. *Here gradients are calculated for all the layers except BN and full-batch BN running stats calculated at step 2 are used.*
5. Perform optimization step.

Doing so, we efficiently update the layers except BN layers as usual for gradient accumulation, calculating running stats and update BN layers on a full-batch. Memory overhead is minor so as it is only BN parameters are updated in a full-batch mode.

What am I missing here?